# What events/actions/methods trigger a http Post request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, express, routes

Consider the following code from an express app:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var standupCtrl = require('../controllers/standup.server.controller');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  return standupCtrl.list(req, res);
});

/* POST filter by member name - home page. */
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    return standupCtrl.filterByMember(req, res);
});

// ............ more code here

module.exports = router;
```

```js
exports.list = function(req, res) {
    var query = Standup.find();

    query.sort({ createdOn: 'desc'}).limit(12).exec(function(err, results){
           res.render('index', {title: 'Standup - List', notes: results});
        });

};

exports.filterByMember = function(req, res) {
    var query = Standup.find();
    var filter = req.body.memberName;

    query.sort({ createdOn: 'desc' });

    if (filter.length > 0)
    {
        query.where({ memberName: filter})
    }

    query.exec(function(err, results) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Standup - List', notes: results });
    });
};
```

I know that when submitting a **form** you can specify a

> method = get/post

For this scenario (where nothing such has been specified) , how does the server know which to trigger (post or get) when user navigates to '/' (e.g. Homepage)?

More generally, My question is:

What events trigger a Post/Get action (if not explicitly specified) ?

(PS: I know typing anything in the address bar of a browser triggers a GET request)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP GET is pretty much the default everywhere if you don't specify otherwise.

Most POSTs are the result of either a form submit or an explicit call via AJAX or as a web service call (like RPC from another server).  You CAN handcraft POST requests using programs like curl, but again that would be rare.  In every toolkit I've seen, it's GET by default.

And rarely (VERY), you might find some RPC provider (such as an IoT or other embedded device) that only speaks POSTs (to save on code space).

Comment: Thank you, BJ but could you refer me to some resource where I could learn more on this. Needless to say, I tried googling for long enough without much luck.

Comment: @KHAN — What more is there to say?

Comment: BJ && Quentin-- Sorry folks, but I am so behind in web dev, even after reading the answer a couple of times, I didn't get it. After some more 'surgical dissection' and 'fragment analysis'  ** now ** I think I do. The most important phrase must be ' ..an explicit call via AJAX or as a web service call .. '.

Comment: @BJ, please forgive a newbie's unforgivable lack of knowledge. Thanks a lot, man :)

Comment: No sweat, @KHAN, we all had to start somewhere.  Check out  https://youtu.be/N-kOM6mvWKo and  https://youtu.be/576WwU7xlWU to see what's happening under the covers and try to make some more sense of what's going on.  Doing HTTP by hand with telnet is particularly useful IMO.  Good luck!

Comment: Much appreciated @BJ. Will surely do. Thanks :)